# Is it possible to find out if my laptop with an Intel CPU has integrated HD graphics?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, graphics-card

I have my old laptop Dell Inspiron N5010 with Intel Core i5 M480 2.67 GHz CPU. It came with dedicated ATI graphic card. The dedicated graphic is showing problems and sometimes crashes the PC.

I disabled ATI graphic card and now my PC runs normal but in low resolutions. I have heard about Intel integrated HD graphics. I am not sure if my PC contains this?

I want to play HD videos in my PC. I am using a dual boot PC with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Do all Intel CPUs contain Intel integrated HD graphics by default? If not how can I check if my PC contain this or not ?

Comment: No, not all Intel CPU's contain Intel integrated HD graphics by default? (not do all AMD chips in case you wonder). Which CPU do you have?  (core i5 is too generic, that like saying 'a four door car'). Once you answer that we could look it up at ark.intel.com

Comment: @Hennes - **i5 M480**

Comment: Easiest way to find out if it works: download a video (MP4, AVI etc.) in HD and try to play it. If it doesn't work, no harm done.

Comment: I guess the dash does make a difference. I tried to look for an "I5 M480" but not for an "I5-M480".

Answer (score 5):

*Note:* I'm not trying to be 'smart' here by saying 'Google is your friend' - ***but***...

Google (other search engines are available ;) is very good at finding "Intel Ark" which is Intel's central repository for information on their products.

So, typing "Intel core i5 M480" directly from your question, the very first hit is Intel Ark & direct information on that CPU chipset - which says it is indeed an Intel® HD Graphics chip, specifically "Intel® HD Graphics for Previous Generation Intel® Processors"

Unfortunately, this chipset is very much 'end-of-life' & support is no longer current.

this is the Intel Ark page - https://ark.intel.com/products/52952/Intel-Core-i5-480M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_66-GHz

Comment: But it has *Intel® Clear Video HD Technology*. Regardless of its age I would think that with proper drivers it should be able to play 1080P content, or not?

Comment: The important point is "with proper drivers". There are none for Win10, idk about ubuntu, but there is definitely no support for Win10, except for a couple of last-ditch legacy drivers Intel released a year or 3 ago. Basically they dropped everything older than the 3000 series & only partially supported the 4000s.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure if my pc contains this.

It does indeed.

[image]

[Intel® Core™ i5-480M Processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/52952/Intel-Core-i5-480M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_66-GHz)

> Do all Intel CPU contain Intel HD graphics by default?

No

> I want to play HD videos on my pc.

The integrated GPU your CPU has isn't very powerful.  You should be able to play videos on it, at what resolution depends, entirely on the video codec of the video. *It is from a processor generation where the integrated GPU wasn't even competitive with the cheapest dedicated GPU.*

> I am using dual boot pc with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04

Intel has not released compatible Windows 10 drivers for your integrated GPU.  Ubuntu 16.04 isn't supported either.

Comment: When I disabled my ATI gpu my pc on ubuntu, it came back from max resolution of 1366x768 to max resolution of 1024x768. I have read somewhere that ubuntu already contains drivers for intel hd graphics. So does it mean my integrated intel gpu  supports max 1024x768 resolution only ?

Comment: And I want to use my pc at 1366x768 anyhow. What version of ubuntu will you suggest which support my integrated gpu ?

Comment: Intel did not release drivers compatible with any version of Ubuntu for that particular iGPU

Comment: "All All Intel CPUs do not contain an integrated Intel GPU.Intel GPU." Hmm, might want to rewrite that as "Not all All Intel CPUs do not contain an integrated  GPU." Some do, some do not, and some even use a non-Intel GPU part".

Comment: @Hennes The question I was answering was if “All Intel CPUs contain an Intel iGPU”, my answer to that question is “All Intel CPUs do not contain an iGPU”.  I feel my answer is perfect for the question that was asked.  It certainly does not eliminate the possibility that some Intel CPUs do contain an Intel iGPU.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if my pc contains this

Download new version of the `PCI ID` list

First, grab the current version of the `pci.ids` file from the Internet:

`$ sudo update-pciids`

OR as root:

`# update-pciids`

Sample outputs:

```
[sudo] password for user: 
Downloaded daily snapshot dated 2014-01-09 03:15:01
```

**How to check graphics card on Linux**

Type the following `lspci` command. It will usually tell you the vendor and model of your card. Open the Terminal/xterminal or shell prompt and type the command:

```
$ lspci
$ lspci -v
$ lspci -v | less

Sample outputs:

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom BCM5785 [HT1000] PCI/PCI-X Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Broadcom BCM5785 [HT1000] Legacy South Bridge
00:02.1 IDE interface: Broadcom BCM5785 [HT1000] IDE
00:02.2 ISA bridge: Broadcom BCM5785 [HT1000] LPC
00:03.0 USB Controller: Broadcom BCM5785 [HT1000] USB (rev 01)
00:03.1 USB Controller: Broadcom BCM5785 [HT1000] USB (rev 01)
00:03.2 USB Controller: Broadcom BCM5785 [HT1000] USB (rev 01)
00:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Rage XL (rev 27)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:0d.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom BCM5785 [HT1000] PCI/PCI-X Bridge (rev b2)
01:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Broadcom BCM5785 [HT1000] SATA (Native SATA Mode)
02:03.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5704 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
02:03.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5704 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

Look for `video controller` / `vga` / `3D` keywords in above output listing and google search your findings.

> I want to play HD videos in my pc.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras vlc libvdpau1 smplayer
```

Then configure SMplayer to use vdpau by going:
Code:

`SMplayer` -> `Options` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Video`

There, set the 'Output driver' to:
Code:

```
vdpau
```

Comment: Even after disabling dedicated ATI card it is still shown on typing `lspci` . And it does not print any Intel gpu information.